# Mudar Layout com o dedo

Tags: java, android

Olá, estou querendo saber como faço para mudar um layout para outro arrastando a tela.... como se fosse em uma galeria mas em vez de fotos seria layouts diferentes

Obrigado!!!

Comment: Poderia ser mais específico? Não da pra entender bem que forma quer exibir esses layouts, da pra imaginar diversas formas de fazer isso. Você precisar especificar melhor sua dúvida ou a sua questão poderá ser considerada ampla de mais.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você tem que usar o componente chamado ViewPager que permite deslizar lateralmente entre diversos Fragments. Para isso vai precisar implementar também um Adapter para o mesmo que irá carregar os Fragments de acordo com a "página" selecionada. E por fim, você pode configurar um layout diferente para cada Fragment.

Maiores detalhes e instruções:

https://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html